# SUM function produces a #VALUE! error when using in array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following values in a sheet (in `A1:G10`) range:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8   8   8   8
9   9   9   9   9   9   9
10  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

I need to calculate the sum of differences of values between two rows in the array above when both rows are defined by row numbers, for example: sum of differences of values between 10-th and 1-st rows, between 9-th and 2-nd rows and so on. Row numbers I defined in `J1:K10` range:

```
1   10
2   9
3   8
4   7
5   6
6   5
7   4
8   3
9   2
10  1
```

Then I selected `L1:L10` range, and in the first cell of it I entered the following formula:

```
=SUM((OFFSET(A1,INDEX(K1:K10,ROW(K1:K10)-ROW(K1)+1)-1,0,1,7)-OFFSET(A1,INDEX(J1:J10,ROW(J1:J10)-ROW(J1)+1)-1,0,1,7)))
```

and then pressed `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` so the formula is enterd as an array formula. And the formula returned a `#VALUE!` error for each cell in the range.
I tried to evaluate the formula, and it evaluates correctly except the last step: `SUM({9,9,9,9,9,9,9})` becomes a `#VALUE!`

Here is a screenshot of the sheet for clarity:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use SUMPRODUCT in L1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX($A$1:$G$10,J1,0)-INDEX($A$1:$G$10,K1,0))
```

and copy down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it pointed me to another way of solving the problem, but I would like to know what's wrong in my formula since it is evaluated correctly until the last step.

Comment: You just need to make the right references absolute and only apply the formula to the first cell, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter ***then*** copy down.

Comment: also you do not need the INDEX in your formula at all: `=SUM((OFFSET($A$1,K1-1,0,1,7)-OFFSET($A$1,J1-1,0,1,7)))` But Offset is volatile and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Excellent! I created the formula that way because didn't know that I can Ctrl+Shift+Enter and then copy down. Of cource, INDEX isn't needed in this case. Thanks!